# Laravel - Model Fields Is Returning Null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a weird issue that is causing my unit tests to fail in Laravel. I have a table that is created like this:

```php
Schema::create('message_threads', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('id')->primary();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->string('user_id');
    $table->string('folder_id')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('starred')->default(false);
    $table->string('thread_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('folder_id')->references('id')->on('message_folders')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

And in its associated model, when I call the getAttributes() function, the fields **starred** and **folder_id** are not present.

```php
//The code
$messageThread = factory(MessageThread::class)->create();
print_r($messageThread->getAttributes());
```

Outputs the followings:

```php
(
    [user_id] => USR-258995103d8c4d37bd6ec3a38dfe9312
    [id] => MTD-cb4f8f66ddfc4385b31155212cb57f91
    [updated_at] => 2020-02-27 14:15:55
    [created_at] => 2020-02-27 14:15:55
)
```

Why are these fields missing, especially the **starred** field, which has a default value of false?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512184/get-laravel-models-with-all-attributes

Answer (score 0):

you may use the `$visible` property to define a white-list of attributes that should be included in your model's array and JSON representation. All other attributes will be hidden when the model is converted to an array or JSON:

```
class MessageThread extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $visible = ['starred', 'folder_id', ...];
}
```